# sidebarLayout Argument

Tags: r, shiny, arguments

I'm havin the following Error in sidebarLayout: argument "mainPanel" is missing, with no default, for the following script:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
titlePanel(title = "Pig breeding trends by country"),
sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
             mainPanel("2000 to 2010"),
             sliderInput(inputId = "year",
                         label = "year by year count:",
                         min = 2000, max = 2010,
                         value = 1)
                        )
                )
       )
)
```

I have checked other threads and it seems to be because the mainPanel isn't in the sidebarLayout but I have checked and its bracketed within no sure what to do now.

Comment: You can't have the mainPanel inside the sidebarPanel - by definition they are different panels. Move the mainPanel out of the sidebar stuff.

Comment: ahhh that explains it! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work:

```
shinyUI(
  fluidPage(
    titlePanel(title = "Pig breeding trends by country"), 
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        sliderInput(inputId = "year", 
                    label = "year by year count:", 
                    min = 2000, 
                    max = 2010, 
                    value = 1) ),
      mainPanel())))
```